# access tr and its content in a table with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, json

I am doing an MVC with C# application. I was trying to access the entire row in a table and change the values in each cell using jquery.

I need to do change the value in each td once a json call is succeeded.

Please advice for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say 'ID' of your table is 'myTable'.

```
$.getJSON('http://yourpageurl.com',
    function(data)
    {
        //Let's say you want to modify all the cells in the first row.
        $('#myTable tr:first td')
            .each(
                function()
                {
                    //'this' represens the cell in the first row.
                    $(this).html('changing cell value');
                }
            );

        //If you want to access all cells of all the rows, replace
        //#myTable tr:first td with
        //'#myTable td'    


    }
);
```

**EDIT:**

If you know 'id' for your tr, you can replace

'#myTable tr:first td' selector with '#<>' replace <> with your TR id.

Comment: the tr in my table will have dynamic values for its id. IN that case, how to access. The Json call will be in a javascript function whick looks like below:

function SubmitReport(id) {
//json goes here
}

Comment: $(this).html('changing cell value'); should be replaced with $(this).children('td').html('changing cell value'); otherwise you will replace the whole td element with new value and as far as I understand you want to replace only the contents of td.

Comment: RaYell, thanks for pointing out the mistake. I corrected the selector.

Comment: Prasad, if your TR's have dynamic ids and you know them, you can use them to access the cells in the particular row.